# Pass a meshgrid as parameter with an array as another parameter

Tags: python, numpy

I seem to recall seeing that it is possible to pass a numpy meshgrid to a function as a parameter along with an array and have the function keep the array whole while iterating the elements of the meshgrid. Did I dream this or does anyone know what I’m referring to? I have searched SOF, google and numpy documentation with no luck.

Example:

```
def makeGridandArray(i=60, j=40, ratio=10):
    arr = np.arange(i*j).reshape(i, j)
    x,y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, i, ratio), np.arange(0, j, ratio), sparse=True)
    return crop(x, y, ratio, arr)

def crop(x, y, ratio,  Arr):
    return np.average(Arr[x:x+ratio, y:y+ratio])
```

The code above will throw an invalid slice error because Arr is being iterated along with the meshgrid.

```
>>> x=makeGridandArray()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/A181F23F-E674-4B44-882C-B03A93E0E84A/Pythonista3/Documents/so.py", line 752, in makeGridandArray
    return crop(x,y, ratio, arr)
  File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/A181F23F-E674-4B44-882C-B03A93E0E84A/Pythonista3/Documents/so.py", line 755, in crop
    return np.average(Arr[x:x+ratio, y:y+ratio])
IndexError: invalid slice
```

In the example above I would expect a 6x4 array returned with the average of every 10x10 subset of Arr. I realize this could be achieved with np.average and reshaping, but what I’m looking for is the syntax of how to pass Arr whole to the function while taking advantage of passing a meshgrid to a function. Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, slicing only accepts integers, e.g: `Arr[1:10, 5:-1]`, but in your code `x` is output of a `meshgrid`, i.e. a numpy array. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @QuangHoang I am very familiar with slicing. As stated in the post I am trying to pass a meshgrid (x and y) to function along with a numpy array and apply the values from the meshgrid to Arr but keep Arr as an array inside the function without iterating it in the same manner as the meshgrid is iterated.

Comment: What kind of meshgrid iteration do you have in mind?  The purpose of using meshgrid is to get arrays that can be used as indices without iteration.  If you must iterate `np.ndindex` is a nicer index generator.  You don't need an extra function layer to test these ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`meshgrid` is just a way of generating two arrays that can index and broadcast together.  For example:

```
In [302]: x,y=np.meshgrid([1,2,3],[4,5,6],sparse=True)                                                 
In [303]: x                                                                                            
Out[303]: array([[1, 2, 3]])
In [304]: y                                                                                            
Out[304]: 
array([[4],
       [5],
       [6]])
```

One is (1,3) shape, the other (3,1); together the produce a (3,3) result

With addition (or other binary math):

```
In [305]: x+y                                                                                          
Out[305]: 
array([[5, 6, 7],
       [6, 7, 8],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

As indices in a 2d array:

```
In [306]: arr = np.arange(1,101).reshape(10,10)                                                        
In [307]: arr[x,y]                                                                                     
Out[307]: 
array([[15, 25, 35],
       [16, 26, 36],
       [17, 27, 37]])
```

An array cannot be used as a slice endpoint:

```
In [310]: np.arange(10)[x: x+3]                                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-310-adcd5e98b614> in <module>
----> 1 np.arange(10)[x: x+3]

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Just because an array is generated by `meshgrid`, it doesn't mean it has special properties, or be used in ways that any other array can't.

Comment: thanks for the post, but I may not have been clear on what I’m looking for. By way of explanation: as I’m sure you know a sparse meshgrid can be passed into a function like `def addTogether(x, y): return x+y` and you’ll get a len(x) by len(y) array back. I believe I saw a post or documentation show how to pass not only the meshgrid by another array and have the other array not be iterated over, but be able to use the array as an array. Not sure if I’m really stating my case well.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to [@hpaulj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61685221/1456927), you can accomplish what you look for using `np.split`:

```
c = np.split(arr,int(i/ratio),axis=0)
d = np.array([np.split(p,int(j/ratio),axis=1) for p in c])
e = np.average(d,axis=(-2,-1))
```

Checks:

```
print(np.average(arr[0:10,0:10])) # 184.5
print(d.shape) # (6, 4, 10, 10)
print(e.shape) # (6, 4)
print(e[0,0]) # 184.5
```